# Get mean on mapply function in r

Tags: r

I have this code here:

```
mat <- cbind(shape,scale_ima)
mapply(rweibull, 10, mat[,"shape"], mat[,"scale_ima"])
```

The mapply function loops through every entry on the mat matrix and for each loop, from the rweibull function i get a vector with 10 entries. I need to find the mean of the vector.

After that i need to store each mean in a new vector, how do i do that?
So, for each mean of the vector i get from the mapply i need to store the data in a vector.

This doesn't work:

```
mapply(mean(rweibull, 10, mat[,"shape"], mat[,"scale_ima"]))
```

Comment: `colMeans(mapply(rweibull, n = 10L, shape = mat[,"shape"], scale = mat[,"scale_ima"]))` Do you need `colMeans`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your expected result:

```
set.seed(42)
colMeans(mapply(rweibull, n = 10L, shape = mat[,"shape"], scale = mat[,"scale_ima"]))
#[1] 0.08762851 0.11618909 0.10013489 0.24263038 0.12706183 0.18069583
#[7] 0.10953056 0.39062035 0.24496276 0.23653724
```

Or

```
set.seed(42)
mapply(function(x,y) mean(rweibull(10, x,y)), mat[,"shape"], mat[,"scale_ima"])
#[1] 0.08762851 0.11618909 0.10013489 0.24263038 0.12706183 0.18069583
# [7] 0.10953056 0.39062035 0.24496276 0.23653724
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(0.953866743, 0.939544872, 0.88055226, 0.937567804, 
0.902443856, 0.969984293, 0.953468872, 0.929905045, 0.889375987, 
0.910115923, 0.152704576, 0.168592082, 0.13059434, 0.153850643, 
0.172734767, 0.162162429, 0.172533372, 0.160826152, 0.190843263, 
0.156289128), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("shape", 
"scale_ima")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to find the mean of each vector and store these means.

```
 result<-mapply(rweibull, 10, mat[,"shape"], mat[,"scale_ima"])

 #get and store the means
 meanStorage<-apply(result,2, mean)
```

To explain why your call to mapply doesn't work, look at the arguments to the function mapply. The first argument is a function, the second to n (denoted by the ...) arguments are the parameters you want to pass into that function.  By calling

```
mapply(mean(....))
```

You pass in the mean function to mapply yet don't have any parameters to mean.